# How to avoid resetting macro definitions within a group/environment

Tags: macros, grouping

Here's the question: why does the following code reset the meaning of the `\pgPtList` control sequence when the group ends?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \gdef\pgPtList{}
    \edef\pgPtList{8}
    pgPtList is: \pgPtList
    
    \edef\pgPtList{8, 5}
    pgPtList is: \pgPtList
\endgroup

Empty environment has ended.

pgPtList is: \pgPtList

\end{document}
```

Here's the output it produces:

```
pgPtList is: 8
pgPtList is: 8, 5
Empty environment has ended.
pgPtList is:
```

My current understanding is that this has something to do with how groups work, so a likely follow-up question is this: how can I redefine the control sequence such that the change sticks once the group ends?

Here's the broader context: I'm trying to typeset an exam and track the number of points on each page, and I'm continually updating `\pgPtList` to keep track of how many points are on each page. At the each of the exam, `\pgPtList` acts as a default parameter to another command that creates a table of point values.

The points on each page are updated within an `enumerate` environment, which is why the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are present in the reprex. Ideally, I'd like to be able to update the `\pgPtList` variable within this environment, even though the point table command will be called outside of it.

My main point of confusion is around `\edef` and `\gdef`. My naive understanding is that these commands are meant to make the resulting control sequences accessible outside of the current group, but the output I get from the code above suggests that something else is happening.

Comment: Welcome! Use `\xdef` rather than `\edef`. `\edef` is local, just as `\def` is. `\xdef` is global, just as `\gdef` is. Note that the `\gdef` definition does survive the group - you don't get an error due to an undefined control sequence. But all your later (re)definitions are local.

Comment: If you are tracking points, you may be better off using a counter rather than commands. If you use a LaTeX counter, it will be global out-of-the-box and you can use calculations to update it e.g. `\addtocounter{mycounter}{2}` or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `\def\macroname<argument specification>{definition}` is a local, standard definition;
- `\edef\macroname<argument specification>{definition}` is a local, expanded definition i.e. `definition` is expanded before assigning `\macroname`;
- `\gdef\macroname<argument specification>{definition}` is a global, standard definition;
- `\xdef\macroname<argument specification>{definition}` is a global, expanded definition.

In your case, the initial definition `\gdef\pgPtList{}` *does* survive the local group. If it did not the use of `\pgPtList` after `\endgroup` would result in an error.

However, all subsequent (re)definitions of `\pgPtList` are explicitly local, so those changes do not survive after `\endgroup` and the meaning of `\pgPtList` reverts to the initial empty definition.

The following example may be helpful:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{tweak}
\setcounter{tweak}{0}
\def\rstatement{Redefinition \thetweak.}

\begingroup
  \gdef\pgPtList{Initial, global definition.}
  pgPtList is: \pgPtList
  
  \edef\pgPtList{\rstatement}
  pgPtList is: \pgPtList ; \stepcounter{tweak}\pgPtList
  
  \def\pgPtList{\rstatement}
  pgPtList is: \pgPtList ; \stepcounter{tweak}\pgPtList
\endgroup

Environment has ended.

pgPtList is: \pgPtList

\begingroup
  \xdef\pgPtList{\rstatement}
  pgPtList is: \pgPtList ; \stepcounter{tweak}\pgPtList
\endgroup

Environment has ended.

pgPtList is: \pgPtList

\begingroup
  \gdef\pgPtList{\rstatement}
  pgPtList is: \pgPtList ; \stepcounter{tweak}\pgPtList
\endgroup

Environment has ended.

pgPtList is: \pgPtList

\end{document}
```

[image: output illustrating local/global & expanded/standard macro definitions]

Note that `\def` and `\gdef` ensure `\pgPtList` uses the value of the counter `tweak` when the macro `\pgPtList` is used, which might not be the value at the time of definition.

In contrast, `\edef` and `\xdef` ensure `\pgfPtList` uses the value of the counter `tweak` at the time of definition, even if the value has changed in the meantime.

On the other hand, both `\def` and `\edef` are local definitions. Their effect ends when then current group ends.

In contrast, `\gdef` and `\xdef` are global. They are effective unless and until some subsequent definition of `\pgfPtList` supersedes them, irrespective of grouping.